# JavaScript get first two words from string in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, javascript-objects

I am new to JavaScript so I am struggling to even know where to start. Please can someone help me.
I have this array of ingredients:

```
const ingris =  [
  "1 cup heavy cream",
  "8 ounces paprika",
  "1 Chopped Tomato",
  "1/2 Cup yogurt",
  "1 packet pasta ",
  "1/2 teaspoon freshly ground black pepper, divided",
]
```

I am trying to take out for example the `1 cup` or `1/2 teaspoon` (first 2 words of the array) and add it to a new array of objects like below:

```
const ShoppingList = [
  {
    val: "heavy cream",
    amount: "1 cup",
  },
  {
    val: "Tomato",
    amount: "1 Chopped ",
  },
  {
    val: "yogurt",
    amount: "1/2 Cup",
  },
];
```

Comment: Break down your big problem into smaller problems. Have you searched ["javascript get first 2 words" on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+get+first+2+words)?

Comment: You can use the split function in a loop to go through all your array elements then grabbing the spilt array and adding the two first elements to the object.

Comment: @blex Yes but this is an array not an individual string

Comment: @Souhailhimself Please can you post an answer because I have no idea how to do that. I would really appreciate all the help you can give me !!!!!!

Comment: It won't work for the pepper...
For tomato, "1" is appropriate - more than "1 chopped".
You'd need to write a language parser...
Split into Quantities, Measurements, Items and bunch the rest (if any) to Comments:
`1/2 teaspoon freshly ground black pepper, divided` => [`1/2`, `teaspoon`], `black pepper`, `freshly ground, divided`...
It can be done, but it's a lot of work.
Perhaps there is something out there for this - but I'd welcome the challenge to code it myself!

Comment: Yes, but now, you know how to do it for a single string. The only thing you have left to figure out is how to loop though an Array

Comment: @iAmOren If you can do that you are a genius!!!!!!! Because I didn't mind having the `freshly ground, divided` but if it can be separated like that please help me I am really struggling

Comment: @Souhailhimself: `split(" ")`....

Comment: Dilhan, you will have to pay me for that - and a lot!  :)

Comment: Correction: It WOULD work for the pepper, just the rest won't be just "pepper"...
Still, logic fails for tomato...

Comment: @Souhailhimself, on my machine, chrome/windows, `split()` returns an array of one element = the whole string...

Comment: "If separator is omitted or does not occur in str, the returned array contains one element consisting of the entire string." - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: @iAmOren That's true my bad I confused it with split in python.

Comment: @Souhailhimself yeah!  It caused me so many headaches...

Comment: at all ... this problem was tackled again by this Q. ... [*"How does one parse best each item of an ingredient list and does create a new object based on each parsing result?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63880334/how-does-one-parse-best-each-item-of-an-ingredient-list-and-does-create-a-new-ob)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably I would try to use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) first iterate through the array of strings and convert it into an new array of objects. On each iteration you can [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string by spaces and most probably the first 2 elements of the array can be the `amount` property and the rest is the value.

See from the documentations:

> The `map()` method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

> The `split()` method divides a String into an ordered list of substrings, puts these substrings into an array, and returns the array.  The division is done by searching for a pattern; where the pattern is provided as the first parameter in the method's call.

Try as the following:

```js
const ingris = [
  "1 cup heavy cream",
  "8 ounces paprika",
  "1 Chopped Tomato",
  "1/2 Cup yogurt",
  "1 packet pasta",
  "1/2 teaspoon freshly ground black pepper, divided",
];

const result = ingris.map(e => {
  const split = e.split(' ');
  const amount = `${split[0]} ${split[1]}`;
  
  return { val: e.replace(`${amount} `, ''), amount };
});

console.log(result);
```

Probably you need to add fallback once you have different format of input strings, like checking if you have at least 3 words in that string.

Comment: Wow @norbitrial thank you so so much You are amazing. How do I add this fallback you talk of?

Comment: @DilhanBhagat With an `if` statement, checking the `length` of the array of `split` like `if (split.length > 2) { }`.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to map the given array to a new one. `Split` the string to an arry at the spaces. return a new object with the first 2 array-elements as val and the others as amount. For gettuing the last elements use [Array#slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [Array#join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) with a space as glue to connect them to a string.

```js
const ingris =  [
  "1 cup heavy cream",
  "8 ounces paprika",
  "1 Chopped Tomato",
  "1/2 Cup yogurt",
  "1 packet pasta ",
  "1/2 teaspoon freshly ground black pepper, divided",
];

let result = ingris.map(str => {
    let arr = str.split(' ');
    return {val: arr[0] + ' ' + arr[1], amount: arr.slice(2).join(' ')};
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approach but using [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to loop over the array, [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to turn each string into a array inside the loop, [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get a slice from the array will help you create what you need. But keep in mind that it currently always get the first 2 words and the words after that. So your ingredients have to be the same way every time

```js
const ingris =  [
  "1 cup heavy cream",
  "8 ounces paprika",
  "1 Chopped Tomato",
  "1/2 Cup yogurt",
  "1 packet pasta ",
  "1/2 teaspoon freshly ground black pepper, divided",
];

const shoppingList = ingris.map(ingredient => {
  const splitIngredient = ingredient.split(' ');
  const amount = splitIngredient.slice(0, 2).join(' ');
  const val = splitIngredient.slice(2, splitIngredient.length).join(' ');
  return { val, amount };
});

console.log(shoppingList);
```